# Amount in Paypal Sandbox Account for Buyer not getting deducted

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal-sdk-rest gem for implementing Paypal in my Rails application. Every thing works fine and the payment is completing successfully and returning me the status as "Complete" while testing from Sandbox account. I Merchant account the amount get added after each transaction but the issue is at Buyer's Account. In Buyer's Account the amount is not getting deducted, even after successful transaction. Is it related to coding part or I have to do some settings in my Sandbox account?

Comment: are you really capturing money?

Comment: Finally I have got the answer for my question. The explanation is as follows:
There's no "real" money movement.In sandbox merchant account will show money was added, yes. With direct credit card transactions (live or sandbox), there is no buyer account to log in to, therefore there's nowhere for us to look for money leaving a buyer account in that situation.
 In the real world, we'd be able to see the money leave the credit card on the card statement.

Comment: Hi,
When i'm trying to pay with sandbox credentials  Error shown :-
        "error_description" = "The client credentials are invalid";